# Compare data between two tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables but in table1 (row and column) there are more record than in table2 and no unique key and not sequence wise record in both table. i want to match record that is table2 record is in table2. what bigquery should i use? its more than 100 000 records and also 120-140 columns

```
Select col1,col2,………from table2
Except distinct 
Select col1,col2,…. From table1
```

But this query is not getting answer for all tables.
And in table no unique key is available data is repeated like id is repeated more time. what should i use?

Answer (score 0):

The except approach gives all lines from table2 which are not in table1.

```sql
with tbl_2 as (select * , "x" as x from unnest([1,1,2,2,3,null]) as a),
tbl_1 as ( select 1 as a , null as x
 union all select 1, "x"
 union all select null, "x")

Select * from tbl_2
except distinct
Select * from tbl_1
```

Please query the sample tables first. You see that `null` entries are treated as normal values. If a line is in table2 several times and only one time in table1, it is not shown.

For doing more complex analyses on how many times a certain row is in each table, hashing all columns are a good way to generate an unique key.

```sql
With tbl_a as (
Select
FARM_FINGERPRINT(
 to_json_string(
  struct(col1,col2,col3 ...)
 )
) as id
from table1
),
tbl_b as (
# same query for table2
....
)

Select *
ifnull(counta,0)-ifnull(countb ,0) as diff
 from
(select id as ida, count(1) as counta from tbl_a group by 1)
full join 
(select id as idb, count(1) as countb from tbl_b group by 1)
on a=b
order by abs(diff) desc
```

Comment: But all rows are not in sequence, so this query is fine for this or not, also null recors are present in many column

Comment: `null` values are treated as valid inputs by converting the struct to a string. With the hash you generate an unique key for each row. What is your final goal? How do you want to handle duplicated lines in one table?

Comment: Can this query is fine to match record , please mention full query , i am having read access only , and i want count of matching each record

Comment: Can i use ,select col1,col2,col3 from table1 Except distinct Select col1,col2,col3 from table2 ;